How can I make a native query using two tables in SpringBoot?
I'm learning Spring Boot and trying to make a custom query that uses two tables, which gives me problems. I was investigating, and because I understood I should use a DTO, but when I called it, it gave me the following error:
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap]

What am I doing wrong?
These are my files
ProducService.java
package com.corellana.bookStore.Product;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO.ListProductsOrderOffer;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;


    public List<ListProductsOrderOffer> findProductsOrderOffer(Integer idCategory){
        return  productRepository.findProductsOrderOffer(idCategory);
    }

}

ProductRepository.java
package com.corellana.bookStore.Product;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO.ListProductsOrderOffer;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>  {
 
    @Query(value ="select p.id_product," + 
    "p.name_product "+
    "from product p " + 
    "inner join editorial e on (p.id_editorial = e.id_editorial) " + 
    "inner join category c on (p.id_category = c.id_category) " + 
    "where c.id_category = :idCategory and p.status_product = true " + 
    "order by p.name_product ASC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ListProductsOrderOffer> findProductsOrderOffer(@Param("idCategory") Integer idCategory);


}

ListProductsOrderOffer.java
package com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder

public class ListProductsOrderOffer {

    public Integer   idProduct;
    public String    nameProduct;
    
}

ProductController.java
package com.corellana.bookStore.Product;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO.ListProductsOrderOffer;
import com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO.ProductDto;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/product")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;


    @GetMapping("/find-products-order-offer")
    public ResponseEntity<?>  findProductsOrderOffer( @RequestParam Integer idCategory){
        
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        List<ListProductsOrderOffer> productDto = productService.findProductsOrderOffer(idCategory)
        .stream()
        .map(Product -> ListProductsOrderOffer.builder()
        .idProduct(Product.getIdProduct())
        .nameProduct(Product.getNameProduct())
        .build())
        .toList();
            
        response.put("data", productDto);
        response.put("success", true);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } 


}

Also check and the error may be due to the type of data, that is, they are different from what they are in the database, so I leave you my table. Additionally, I verified that the query would not present problems, so I decided to simplify it.


Use Alias with column names so values could be mapped with your DTO
@Query(value ="select p.id_product as idProduct," + 
"p.name_product as nameProduct "+
"from product p " + 
"inner join editorial e on (p.id_editorial = e.id_editorial) " + 
"inner join category c on (p.id_category = c.id_category) " + 
"where c.id_category = :idCategory and p.status_product = true " + 
"order by p.name_product ASC", nativeQuery = true)
List<ListProductsOrderOffer> findProductsOrderOffer(@Param("idCategory") Integer idCategory);


This doesn't work, I had already tried it before, I even changed the fields in the discount to id_product and name_product

Make ListProductsOrderOffer interface and define getters Integer getIdProduct() and String getNameProduct()
It should work.

I think this should do:
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>  {
 
    @Query(value ="select new com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO.ListProductsOrderOffer(p.id_product, p.name_product) "+
    "from product p " + 
    "inner join editorial e on (p.id_editorial = e.id_editorial) " + 
    "inner join category c on (p.id_category = c.id_category) " + 
    "where c.id_category = :idCategory and p.status_product = true " + 
    "order by p.name_product ASC")
    List<ListProductsOrderOffer> findProductsOrderOffer(@Param("idCategory") Integer idCategory);

}

update on Apr 3:

make ListProductsOrderOffer being an interface

package com.corellana.bookStore.ProductDTO;

public interface ListProductsOrderOffer {
    Integer getIdProduct();
    String getNameProduct();
}


modify your original Repo to this:

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>  {
 
    @Query(value ="select p.id_product as idProduct," + 
    "p.name_product as nameProduct "+
    "from product p " + 
    "inner join editorial e on (p.id_editorial = e.id_editorial) " + 
    "inner join category c on (p.id_category = c.id_category) " + 
    "where c.id_category = :idCategory and p.status_product = true " + 
    "order by p.name_product ASC", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ListProductsOrderOffer> findProductsOrderOffer(@Param("idCategory") Integer idCategory);

}


This does not work. Generates an error when trying to run the application

could you parse the error here?

Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.corellana.bookStore.Product.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.corellana.bookStore.Product.ProductRepository.findProductsOrderOffer(java.lang.Integer); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.corellana.bookStore.Product.ProductRepository.findProductsOrderOffer(java.lang.Integer)

I think you should make the ListProductsOrderOffer interface. let me modify my code above.

This only causes more problems, this does not even compile the code

Whenever writting a native query always make nativeQuery = true , and for join queries
and whatever you are returning it should be comodated in object in your case ProductsOrderOffer

If you notice that is already in my code

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
